# Representation theorem for Heyting algebras?

Tags: reference-request, logic

A fundamental theorem by Stone asserts that any Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of the archetypical Boolean algebras, that is the power sets of a set $X$ (equipped with intersection, union and complementation).

I was wondering whether a similar result carries over to Heyting algebras, that is whether it is true or not that any (complete) Heyting algebras is isomorphic to a subalgebra of the Heyting algebra given by the open subsets of a topological space. If this is not the case (as I suspect), is there any prototype of Heyting algebra which every Heyting algebra (complete or not) can be proven to be isomorphic to?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MarcoVergura: Just a remark: If every Boolean algebra was isomorphic to some powerset, then there would be no countable Boolean algebras.

Comment: The difficulty, in some sense, is the Heyting implication. Every Heyting algebra is a distributive lattice, and every distributive lattice can be embedded in a complete Heyting algebra, but this is an embedding of _distributive lattices_, not Heyting algebras. On the other hand, not every distributive lattice can be embedded as a subalgebra of the distributive lattice of open subsets of a topological space – this is the question of whether there are "enough points".

Comment: Have you checked Dunn and Hardegree's *Algebraic Methods in Philosophical Logic*? On p. 385, they claim that every Heyting algebra is isomorphic to a Heyting algebra of open sets. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Have you checked in Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski, *The Mathematics of Metamathematics* (1963), **Ch.IV. Pseudo-Boolean algebras**, page 128 : **§3. Representation theorems**. "The following theorem explain the connection between pseudo-Boolean algebras and topological Boolean algebras: For every pseudo-boolean algebra $A$ there exists a topological Boolean algebra $B$ such that $A = \mathfrak S(B)$ [McKinsey and Tarski, 1946]" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Esakia Duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esakia_duality) might just be the thing that you are looking for.

For every Heyting algebra $A$ there exists a so called [Esakia space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esakia_space) $\mathscr{X}=(X,
\leq, 
\mathscr{O})$, which is a certain kind of ordered topological space, such that $A$ is isomorphic to the Heyting algebra of clopen up-sets of $\mathscr{X}$.

This gives a dual equivalence between the category of Heyting algebras and the category of Esakia spaces, very similar to the well-know Stone duality between Boolean algebras and Stone spaces. However the category of Esakia spaces is not a full subcategory of the category of ordered topological spaces and continuous and order preserving functions between them.

Finally you can give a purely topological description of the category of Esakia spaces, in the sense that it is isomorphic to a (non full) subcategory of the category of Spectral spaces and spectral maps see [Bezhanishvili et al. 2010](http://www.phil.uu.nl/~bezhanishvili/Papers/PairwiseStoneRevised.pdf) Theorem 7.12.