# Having trouble thinking of homeomorphisms as topological isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, soft-question, definition

In short: I find it intuitive that isomorphic algebraic structures (be it groups, rings, fields, vector spaces,...) have the same algebraic properties. Yet I do not find it as intuitive that two homeomorphic topological spaces have the same properties (insofar as these properties deal exclusively with their topology). Instead I find it intuitive to define a 'topological isomorphism' not as a homeomorphism, but as I have defined it below so as to follow the pattern of defining isomorphisms in algebra.

**The next section can be skipped;** it just serves to explain why I find algebraic isomorphisms intuitive, as opposed to homeomorphisms, as well as to why I think homeomorphisms 'break the pattern' in terms of how isomorphisms are defined in algebra. **My concise questions are at the end of the post.**

---

As I see it, an group isomorphism $\phi:(G_1,+)\to (G_2,\times)$ is a 'renaming' of the elements of $G_1$ and of its operator: any $x\in G_1$ is renamed to $\phi(x)\in G_2$, and $+$ is renamed to $\times$. Under that view "$x + y = z$" says the same as "$\phi(x)\times\phi(y) = \phi(z)$", yet with different symbols.

*Given two isomorphic groups $(G_1, +)$ and $(G_2, \times)$ **it is intuitive to me** that any 'group-theoretic' property holds in one group if and only if it holds in the other.*

A vector space consists of an abelian group of vectors $(V,+_V)$, a field of scalars $(F,+,\times)$, and scalar multiplication $(\cdot):F\times V$. Thus a vector space can be seen as a $6$-tuple $(V,+_V, F, +, \times, \cdot)$. I would define a 'vector space isomorphism' between $(V_1,+_{V_1}, F_1, +_1, \times_1, \cdot_1)$ and $(V_2,+_{V_2}, F_2, +_2, \times_2, \cdot_2)$ as a pair $(f,g)$ of bijections $f:V_1\to V_2$ and $g:F_1\to F_2$ that 'preserve vector space operations' i.e.

1. $f(v+_{V_1}u)=f(v)+_{V_2}f(u)$ for any $v,u\in V_1$.
2. $g(a+_1b)=g(a)+_1g(b)$ for any $a,b\in F_1$.
3. $g(a\times_1b)=g(a)+_1g(b)$ for any $a,b\in F_1$.
4. $f(a\cdot_1v)=g(a)\cdot_2 f(v)$ for any $a\in F_1, v\in V_1$.

Essentially I'm saying that $f$ is a bijective linear map, that $g$ is a field isomorphism, and that $f$ and $g$ 'preserve' scalar multiplication i.e. $4)$ holds. A linear map is a specific case of the above. As with groups, it is possible to see $f$ and $g$ as 'renaming' the vectors, scalars, and operations between them.

*Given two vector spaces and a bijective linear map between them, **it is intuitive to me** that any 'linear-algebra-theoretic' property holds in one vector space if and only if it holds in the other.*

That intuition remains with me for all algebraic structures I have studied, however *given two topological spaces and a homeomorphism (often called a "topological isomorphism") between them, **it is not intuitive to me** that any property (that deals exclusively with their topology) holds in one space if and only if it holds in the other.* The reason being that a homeomorphism does not seek to preserve any operators (unlike group isomorphisms, linear maps, etc). If it was defined so as to preserve 'topological operators' it would -I think- be defined as follows:

---

**Definition:** given two topological spaces $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ a ***topological isomorphism*** $(f,\phi)$ is a pair of bijections $f:X\to Y$ and $\phi:\tau_X\to\tau_Y$ that preserve 'topological operations' i.e.

1. Given $x\in X$ and $A\in \tau_X$, we have that $x\in A$ if and only if $f(x)\in \phi(X)$.
2. Given an arbitrary collection $\{A_\alpha\}\subseteq \tau_X$ we have
   $$\phi\left(\bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha\right) = \bigcup_\alpha \phi(A_\alpha).$$
3. Given $A,B\in\tau_X$ we have
   $$\phi\left(A\cap B\right) = \phi(A)\cap \phi(B).$$

The following results are almost immediate. Notably, since $1)$ and $2)$ below deal with concepts which definition does not require us to use "$\in$" (closed sets, basis, countability) their proof requires only the use of $\phi$. However, since the definition of a Hausdorff space uses the $\in$ operator, the proof of $3)$ below does make use of $f$, the function which "translates" $\in$ from $(X,\tau_X)$ to $(Y,\tau_Y$)

**Theorem:** if there is some topological isomorphism $(f,\phi)$ between $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$, then

1. $A$ is closed in $\tau_X$ if and only if $f(A^c)$ is closed in $\tau_Y$.
2. $\tau_X$ is second-countable if and only if so is $\tau_Y$.
3. $\tau_X$ is Hausdorff if and only if so is $\tau_Y$.
4. $\ldots$

---

**Why are topological isomorphisms (as I have defined them) not ever used in topology?**

**How do topological isomorphisms relate to homeomorphisms?**

---

PS: I know very little universal algebra or category theory.

Comment: **By definition**, a [topological property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) is a property that is preserved by homeomorphisms.

Comment: @morrowmh right, I should change my terminology.

Comment: What you've defined would be related to the topic of point-free topology, where you forget $X$ and $Y$ entirely and instead consider only the algebraic objects $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$ (though in that subject, a "morphism of frames" $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(\tau_X, \tau_Y)$ is a function map in the opposite direction which preserves sups and finite meets, in order to correspond to what a continuous function $X \to Y$ induces on the collections of open sets).

Comment: Groups and topological spaces have a certain differences and certain commonalities. A group structure on $G$ is built from Cartesian powers. The group operation is a binary operation, which is a certain subset of $G^3=G \times G \times G$. The inverse operation on $G$ is a function from $G$ to itself, which is a certain subset of $G^2=G \times G$. But a topological structure on $X$ is built on power sets: the topology on $X$, which is a certain collection of subsets, is a certain subset of $\mathcal P(X)$, which is a certain element of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$.

Comment: So much for the differences. The commonality is: a bijection $f : A \to B$ induces a bijection $A^2 \to B^2$ and a bijection $A^3$ to $B^3$ and a bijection $\mathcal P(A) \to \mathcal P(B)$ and a bijection $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A)) \to \mathcal P(\mathcal P(B))$. So, for both groups and homeomorphisms, an isomorphism is a bijection that takes the structure to the structure under the appropriate induced bijection.

Comment: As others have mentioned, $f$ does most of the work in your definition. Regarding the extent of work $\phi$ does without a reference to $f$, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867090/169085 is relevant.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\mathcal{X}=(X,\tau), \mathcal{Y}=(Y,\sigma)$. Your topological isomorphisms are equivalent to homeomorphisms in the following sense:

1. If $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ is a homeomorphism then there is exactly one function $g:\tau\rightarrow\sigma$ such that $(f,g)$ is a topological isomorphism.
2. If $(f,g)$ is a topological isomorphism from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$.

For $1$, the unique $g$ is the function $U\mapsto\{f(u): u\in U\}$. **In fact, note that the "set-map part" always has this form in any topological isomorphism.** For $2$, continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ follow from the "$x\in A\iff f(x)\in g(A)$" condition.

I've kept things deliberately sketchy here; writing out the details of this proof is a good exercise, and I think will help build intuition for homeomorphisms. As to why we don't use this notion, I think it's just a matter of efficiency: no information is lost by discarding the "sets-map" part.

Comment: As it's past midnight here I will do the exercise tomorrow, but I already find your answer helpful so +1. Do you happen to know why the definition I gave is never used?

Comment: @Sam See the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: @Sam: Let me weigh in on the question in your latest comment, with a slight spin on the last sentence of this answer: the ordered pair $(f,\phi)$ determines and is determined by its first entry $f$, so it is simpler to let $f$ alone be the "isomorphism" object.

Comment: The mathematical culture generally prefers definitions (like axioms) to be as spare and efficient as possible.